# postfix: deliver mail to specific emai addresses locally and send the rest to relayhost

Tags: postfix

I want to achieve the following with postfix:

Almost all outgoing emails shall be sent via a relayhost, configured in main.cf with

```
relayhost = my.mailserver
```

There's one specific email address (bugs@mydomain.com) for which I want the email to be delivered locally. I set up a local account on the machine to match the email address and added "mydomain.com" to the mydestination property in main.cf. Then of course postfix tries to deliver every email to @mydomain.com locally and bounces them because the respective user doesn't exist.

Question [Hybrid gmail MX + postfix for local accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/149453/hybrid-gmail-mx-postfix-for-local-accounts) seems to be somewhat related (though more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the correct syntax in the transport configuration file:

Add the following to /etc/posfix/transport:

```
bugs@mydomain.com :
*    relay:[my.mailserver]
```

and run

```
postmap transport
postfix reload
```

Comment: hmm this does not work for me - still relays 'bugs@mydomain.com'.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is add the following to `/etc/posfix/transport`

```
bugs@mydomain.com local:
*     relay:[my.mailserver]
```

Then add the following to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Then run:

```
sudo postmap hash:/etc/postfix/transport
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```